# How to make raw pointer to parent struct in rust

Tags: pointers, rust, raw

sorry for my poor english
I'm a new rust programer from c++ and trying to
make the job done.

Player has many sub module, and then usualy reffence each other.
In c++ , we like to save a pointer to Player, so I can access other
module or method easilly. I can't imagine how to orginze code under
rust's safty check mechenism. Then I try to use raw pointer , but still failed.
Here is my codes:

```
struct Task {
    id: u32,
    status: u32,
}

struct TaskMgr {
    tasks: Vec<Task>,
    pl: *mut Player
}

impl TaskMgr {
    fn get_owner(&mut self) -> &mut Player {
        unsafe {
            &mut *self.pl
        }
    }
    fn submit_task(&mut self, id: u32) {
        unsafe {
            (*self.pl).add_item(1000, 1);
        }
    }
    fn on_add_item(&mut self, id: u32, cnt: u32) {
        println!("task on add item {} {} items len:{}", id, cnt, self.tasks.len());
        self.tasks[0].status =2;
    }
}

struct Item {
    id: u32,
    cnt: u32,
}

struct ItemMgr {
    items: Vec<crate::Item>,
    pl: *mut Player
}

struct Player
{
    task_mgr: TaskMgr,
    item_mgr: ItemMgr,
}

impl Default for Player {
    fn default() -> Self {
        let mut r = Self {
            task_mgr: TaskMgr { tasks: vec![Task { id: 1, status: 0 }], pl: std::ptr::null_mut() },
            item_mgr: ItemMgr { items: vec![Item { id: 1000 , cnt: 1}],pl: std::ptr::null_mut() },
        };
        unsafe {
            r.task_mgr.pl = std::ptr::addr_of_mut!(r);
            r.item_mgr.pl = &mut r;
        }
        r
    }
}

impl Player {
    fn submit_task(&mut self, id: u32) {
        self.task_mgr.submit_task(id);
    }

    fn on_add_item(&mut self, id: u32, cnt: u32) {
        self.task_mgr.on_add_item(id, cnt);
    }

    fn add_item(&mut self, id: u32, cnt: u32) {
        let i = self.item_mgr.items.iter_mut().find(|x| x.id == id);
        if i.is_some() {
            i.unwrap().cnt += 1;
        }
        self.on_add_item(id, cnt);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut pl = Player::default();
    pl.submit_task(1);

}
```

output will be

```
task on add item 1000 2 items len:486381840784
```

items len is obviously wrong, why ? how to fix it
std::ptr::addr_of_mut!(r) or *mut r both dont work
if I move pointer assignment out of default() function, it sounds work.

```
    let mut pl = Player::default();
    unsafe {
        pl.task_mgr.pl = &mut pl as *mut Player;
        pl.item_mgr.pl = &mut pl as *mut Player;
    }
```

but this will make code hard to use
how to assgin raw pointer when Player create

Comment: As soon as `default()` returns, then `Player` is moved. So the `*mut Player` address that you just copied, is no longer valid. Depending on what the overall goal is, then you might be able to use [`Rc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html). If you need a mutable reference as well, then combine it with [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html). However, having to use that, already suggests poor design. So instead I'd recommend separating `Player` from `TaskMgr`

Comment: @vallentin  In game developing, Player  object usually has many sub modules, and they call eachother through Player's interface.   I has tried to use esc framework. But it seens very complex. Would you please explain the separating in the classic rust way in detail?  some code may help me a lot,  or a simlar project best?

Comment: "New Rust programmer" should avoid using unsafe code for non-necessary thing (i.e. interop).

Comment: You're trying to write C++ using rust and you're going to have a bad time if you keep trying. Don't use unsafe while you're learning. Try to find a way to reorganize your data so that you don't need to store references or pointers at all. Try simply passing references to the methods that really need them, it plays way more nicely with Rust's type system: `struct TaskMgr { tasks: Vec<Task> }  impl Task { fn submit_task(&mut self, id: u32, player: &mut Player) { // ...`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> How to make raw pointer to parent struct in Rust?

I think you can obtain a **reference** to the parent struct and then **convert** it to a raw pointer using the `as` keyword. Something like this:

```
struct ParentStruct {
    value: i32,
}

struct ChildStruct {
    parent: *const ParentStruct,
}

fn main() {
    let parent = ParentStruct { value: 10 };
    let child = ChildStruct { parent: &parent as *const ParentStruct };

    // Accessing parent value through raw pointer in child.
    unsafe {
        let parent_ref = &*child.parent;
        println!("Parent value: {}", parent_ref.value);
    }
}
```

Docs: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.as.html

Comment: Technically, this doesn't address the issue. The issue being that `Player` is moved, so the address stored in `TaskMgr` becomes invalid as soon as `default()` returns

Answer (score 1):

Your code contains Undefined Behavior (use-after-move), as running it under Miri shows. Your "solution" also has UB. **New Rust users should not write unsafe code, and even experienced users should avoid it unless they are sure there is no alternative.**

If you insist on this design, the proper answer will be to hold `Weak<RefCell<Player>>`. However, this is a code smell. As can be seen this is also very awkward and prone to panics:

```rust
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::{Rc, Weak};

struct Task {
    id: u32,
    status: u32,
}

struct TaskMgr {
    tasks: Vec<Task>,
    pl: Weak<RefCell<Player>>,
}

impl TaskMgr {
    fn get_owner(&self) -> Rc<RefCell<Player>> {
        self.pl.upgrade().unwrap()
    }
    fn submit_task(&self, id: u32) {
        self.get_owner().borrow_mut().add_item(1000, 1);
    }
    fn on_add_item(&mut self, id: u32, cnt: u32) {
        println!(
            "task on add item {} {} items len:{}",
            id,
            cnt,
            self.tasks.len()
        );
        self.tasks[0].status = 2;
    }
}

struct Item {
    id: u32,
    cnt: u32,
}

struct ItemMgr {
    items: Vec<crate::Item>,
    pl: Weak<RefCell<Player>>,
}

struct Player {
    task_mgr: TaskMgr,
    item_mgr: ItemMgr,
}

impl Player {
    fn new() -> Rc<RefCell<Self>> {
        let mut r = Rc::new_cyclic(|this| {
            RefCell::new(Self {
                task_mgr: TaskMgr {
                    tasks: vec![Task { id: 1, status: 0 }],
                    pl: Weak::clone(this),
                },
                item_mgr: ItemMgr {
                    items: vec![Item { id: 1000, cnt: 1 }],
                    pl: Weak::clone(this),
                },
            })
        });
        r
    }
}

impl Player {
    fn submit_task(&self, id: u32) {
        self.task_mgr.submit_task(id);
    }

    fn on_add_item(&mut self, id: u32, cnt: u32) {
        self.task_mgr.on_add_item(id, cnt);
    }

    fn add_item(&mut self, id: u32, cnt: u32) {
        let i = self.item_mgr.items.iter_mut().find(|x| x.id == id);
        if i.is_some() {
            i.unwrap().cnt += 1;
        }
        self.on_add_item(id, cnt);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut pl = Player::new();
    pl.borrow_mut().submit_task(1);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f20ab0ec8921a28a20642a94e8e482b1).

This *can* be made to work, but will still be in a bad shape.

The truth is, what you're trying to do is to build a [self-referential struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct), which Rust is known for not-liking. The best way to approach self-referential structs is to avoid them; they're notoriously hard to get correctly. Re-design your app to not use them. I can't tell how exactly because I don't know your exact interface, but it's often possible, more often than you might believe.

If you cannot, use a library that wraps them nicely is an option too: using ECS libraries in Rust is common for that reason in game development. Actually building self-referential structs yourself should be the last resort, and using unsafe code for that should be absolutely forbidden unless you truly, 100% know what you're doing and you're an experienced Rust developer.

Answer (score -2):

I use Box to move raw pointer assginment where Player created finally

```
impl Player {
fn new() -> Box<Self> {
    let mut r = Box::new(Self {
        task_mgr: TaskMgr { tasks: vec![Task { id: 1, status: 0 }], pl: std::ptr::null_mut() },
        item_mgr: ItemMgr { items: vec![Item { id: 1000 , cnt: 1}], pl: std::ptr::null_mut() },
    });
    unsafe {
        r.task_mgr.pl = &mut *r;
        r.item_mgr.pl = &mut *r;
    }
    r
}
```

}

Comment: This code is Undefined Behavior and **must be avoided at all costs**.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).